# How to verify Array of objects is empty/null/undefined in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a js array of objects as follows:

```
var person = [{
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 46
}, {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "",
  age: 35
}];
```

How do i find out if at least of the objects in the array, for eg `firstName:` or `lastName:` is empty or not? The result of the called function needs only to be `true` or `false`.

Comment: `npm install joi` if it is in node. for browsers there are also plenty of validators of all kinds

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use filter & length like:

```
const isEmpty = person.filter(x => !x.firstName || !x.lastName).length > 0
```

Or, using [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) like:

```
const isEmpty = person.some(x => !x.firstName || !x.lastName);
```

<sup>**EDIT:-**</sup>

```
function filterItems(TableData) {
  return TableData.filter(function(el) {
    return Object.values(el).some(v => !v);
  })
}
```

Comment: Use `Array#some` instead to get rid of the length check

Comment: Thanks for prompt response. But in case we need to generalize the code with n number of objects in each array element then?

Comment: @palaѕн OP means an arbitrary amount of object values. So `person.some(x => Object.values(x).some(val => !val))`

Comment: I am trying something like this                 `function filterItems(TableData) {
   return TableData.filter(function(el) {
    
    return isEmpty(el);
   })
 }
 
 function isEmpty(item) {
  if(item.length > 0){   
   return false;//this element is NOT empty
  }else{
     return true;//this element is empty
  }
 }`

Comment: @palaѕн, yes `TableData` is receiving the Array named `person`

Comment: I think too many `return` is creating problem and not allowing all items to be verified before giving final `true` or `false`

Comment: yes sir, works truly smooth. This is of course a generalized function applicable to any array of objects. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `forEach` to iterate over the array and use `Object.values` to get all the value. Then use `indexOf` to test if the value matches.Use a variable to save the state

```js
var person = [{
    firstName: "",
    lastName: "Doe",
    age: 46
  },
  {
    firstName: "John",
    lastName: "",
    age: 35
  }
];

function testArray(arr) {
  var isEmpty = false
  arr.forEach(function(item) {
    if (Object.values(item).indexOf("") !== -1) {
      isEmpty = true
    }

  })
  return isEmpty;
}
console.log(testArray(person))
```

Answer (score 1):

If at least one item is null or empty, it returns false

```js
const person = [{
  firstName: "",
  lastName: "Doe",
  age: 46
}, {
  firstName: "John",
  lastName: "",
  age: 35
}];

const allItemsHaveValue = person.map(o => Object.values(o).every(v => v)).every(v => v);

console.log('All items have value: ', allItemsHaveValue);
```